# how to make CSS shorter with toggle class .dark-theme

Tags: css, refactoring

While toggling .dark-theme CSS starts to look enormous. Is there a way to make it more elegant?

Here is just little piece of example below:

```
body.dark-theme .new-task__txt,
body.dark-theme .tasks-list__i,
body.dark-theme .card__footer,
body.dark-theme .tasks-list__i .round label,
body.dark-theme .round label {
  background: hsl(237, 14%, 26%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use scss it makes code more elegant by it self.
ex.

```
body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;

  ...
  .new_text {
     ...
   }
}
```